# I want to content grab a specific point of data using curl

Tags: curl

I am trying to grab a specific piece of data on a website to echo it back on my website (the absolute gain).  The webpage in question is: http://www.myfxbook.com/members/berezhnoi/my-investors-account-1/202250 and I want the Absolute gain to be moved onto my website without the rest of the results.

I am using the code below which is great for displaying the whole website but I only want one figure marked by the source code in between Abs. Gain: and /li> that is currently 22%.

```
<?php
  $curl = curl_init();
  $url = 'http://www.myfxbook.com/members/berezhnoi/my-investors-account-1/202250';
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  echo $result;
```

?>

Obviously this data changes everyday. Would be happy for any help.